# Changing Default JSON Time Format with RESTEasy 3.x

Tags: java, json, jackson, resteasy

I am using RESTEasy to implement a REST Service using JSON serialization.  Currently, Dates are getting serialized to milliseconds since 1970.  To improve compatibility, I would like to get my dates into one of two formats; milliseconds + timezone offset or ISO 8061.

It seems that RESTEasy used to use Jettison for JSON serialization, but from what I've been reading they've switch to Jackson ... all of this has made googling for help pretty hit or miss.

From what I can tell, I need to implement a ContextResolver along the lines of:

```
    public class JacksonConfig impelments ContextResolver<ObjectMapper>
    {
        private final OBjectMapper objectMapper;

        public JacksonConfig() throws Exception
        {
            objectMapper = new ObjectMapper.configure(
                               SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATE_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
        }

        @Override
        public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> arg0)
        {
            return objectMapper;
        }
     }
```

The thing I haven't been able to find, is what do I do with this?  Where do I put it?

So the larger questions are, am I heading in the right direction and are my assumptions correct?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to register your `ContextResolver` implementation with Resteasy.  You can do this by annotating your class with the `@Provider` annotation and allowing Resteasy to automatically scan it during startup, registering it in web.xml, or registering it in a class that extends `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` (if that is how you are bootstrapping Resteasy).

### Registering via Annotations

```
@Provider
public class JacksonConfig implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper>
{
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public JacksonConfig() throws Exception
    {
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper.configure(
                           SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATE_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> arg0)
    {
        return objectMapper;
    }
 }
```

Verify that classpath scanning is enabled in your web.xml file like so:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

**NOTE:** If you are deploying this in JBoss 7 do not set the `resteasy.scan` context parameter as it is enabled by default.

### Registering via web.xml

Add the following context parameter to your `web.xml` file.  The value of the parameter should be the fully qualified class name of your `ContextResolver`.

```
<context-param>
      <param-name>resteasy.providers</param-name>
      <param-value>foo.contextresolver.JacksonConfig</paramvalue>
</context-param>
```

### Registering via Application

If you are using an Application class to configure Resteasy you can add your provider to the set of services and providers to register with Resteasy like so:

```
public class MyApp extends Application 
{
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() 
    {
        HashSet<Class<?>> set = new HashSet<Class<?>>(2);
        set.add(JacksonConfig.class);
        set.add(MyService.class);
        return set;
    }
}
```

[More on standalone configuration HERE](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.4.Final/userguide/html_single/#d4e111)

Comment: Thanks for the post, I've gotten quite a bit further, but still haven't cracked the nut.  I see my JacksonConfig constructor being called, but I never see the getContext method getting called.  If it helps, I am using a WebApplicationContext in Jetty and registering via web.xml.  The fact that I see construction makes me think that the web.xml is correct ... just missing one last piece.

Comment: And I fixed it ... I was using RESTEasy 3.0.4.  I rolled back to 2.3.5 and everything is working.  Thanks for the help!  And now to open a RESTEasy bug.

Comment: For migrating to Wildfly 8.1.0 / Resteasy 3.0.8 the same registering by provider should work but the import changes to `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature` due to use of Jackson 2.

Comment: Not working for me ... I'm using resteasy 3.0.8 in wildfly 8.1.0, using com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature the configure method off the ObjectMapper yelds The method configure(SerializationConfig.Feature, boolean) in the type ObjectMapper is not applicable for the arguments (SerializationFeature, boolean)

Answer (score 6):

Using with the JSR310 (new api date) - LocalDate, LocalDateTime, LocalTime

Add dependence:

```
<dependency> 
     <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId> 
     <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId> 
     <version>2.4.0</version> 
</dependency>
```

And create a provider to register the module:

```
@Provider
public class JacksonConfig implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {
private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

public JacksonConfig() throws Exception {

    objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
                .disable( SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS )
                .disable( SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS )
                .setSerializationInclusion( JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL )
                .registerModule( new JSR310Module() );

}

@Override
public ObjectMapper getContext( Class<?> arg0 ) {
    return objectMapper;
} }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just annotate your fields with (note the string literal could be externalized/referred from a constant):

```
@javax.json.bind.annotation.JsonbDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")
Date myDate;
```

Comment: Using WildFly 21 with Jave EE 8 and this works a lot better then all the other solutions... Tnx!